# How to delete/update form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form I am able too add data but I cannot seem to update or delete it.

Also any idea why the id is only returning an ID of 1 when I  submit an item? Here is a link to my code sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-pond-vtu51

Answer (score 0):

**For unique IDs**
According to your code, you are always passing the id as 1. You need to increment it based on what's in your state.

In you click handler, you may use something like this to get what id to assign:

```
    const idToAssign = items.length ? parseInt(items[items.length-1].id)+1 : 1;
```

If the items state is empty, it will return 1 else it will add 1 to the latest item's id value. This will ensure that you have unique ids for all your items.

**Removing an item**

To remove an item from your array, first make sure you're passing the index to the remove function instead of the id then use the following to remove an item:

```
array.splice(index, 1);
```

If you want to remove an item based on it's value then use the [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
    const filteredItems = items.filter(obj => { return obj.id !== id });
```

**Updating an Item**
You can do something like this to update an item:

```
const updateTodo = (index) => {
  const updateValue = prompt('New value');
  if(updateValue){
    //create a copy of items
    const newItems = [...items];
    //create a copy of item that needs to be updated
    const updateItem = {...newItems[index]};
    //update the value the needs to be changed
    updateItem.itemName = updateValue;
    //put the item back
    newItems[index] = updateItem;
    //update the state
    setItems(newItems);
  }
}
```

Check this out: [https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-https-skrlp](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-https-skrlp?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your id to 0 rather than 1 to make things more easier.
Secondly, in the handleAddButtonClick function I assign the id: to the most recent items.length, to make it dynamic.

Lastly, I sort the items array using a filter method to return every items except for the one that is not equal to the clicked current id, which automatically removes it.

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([{ itemName: "Test", id: 0 }]);

const handleAddButtonClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newItem = {
       itemName: inputValue,
       id: items.length
    };
    //...
 };

 const removeTodo = (id) => {
     console.log(id);
     setItems(items.filter(item => item.id !== id));
 };
```